# Creating a list from a range of numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create a list of size 9 (but that can change) which is populated with numbers from the range of [-pi/2,pi/2] where basically the range is split into 9 numbers and those 9 numbers are what the list is populated with.

Comment: IIUC, you're looking for [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). Looking for a dupe.

Comment: TL; DR: `np.linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,n)`

Comment: Do you want the `pi/2` end point?  There's a difference between how `np.arange` and `np.linspace` handle end points.

Comment: Yes, I do want pi/2 as the endpoint. Linspace did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
numpy.linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,9)
```

Goes from -pi/2 to pi/2 in 9 steps

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import numpy as np

liste=np.arange(-math.pi/2, math.pi/2+0.01, math.pi/8)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22328139)

Comment: The superficiality of the review comments bugs me.  That said, you should display `liste`.  Other answers and comments use `linspace`.  It handles the end point better.